# How does Oracle APEX generate Swagger doc

Tags: oracle, swagger, oracle-apex

I was working on Some API documentation, we have an option to Generate "swagger doc" on module itself.

The question I wanted to ask was how does Oracle generate it?

Is there a table in ORACLE DB we can see the same JSON data?

Comment: with code...we don't store anything in the db as json, we generate the json dynamically from both the data dictionary (what tables, what columns, what data types...) and how the REST APIs are defined in our ords_metadata schema

Comment: I don't think you can query the json data - I'd think it is generated on the fly based on the ORDS data dictionary views. There are a couple of blogs explaining how it works: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-open-api-swagger-support and
https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddlewaresupport/post/generating-a-swagger-document-through-ords-based-restful-services-in-apex

Comment: also, APEX doesn't generate the OpenAPI itself, it calls the Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) APIs which generates the OpenAPI json, which can be used in swagger tooling

Comment: @thatjeffsmith is there a way to see that code?

Comment: sorry @EAZY_EZ_HE, no - ORDS isn't open source

Comment: ok so one question is there a way to create api docs with only just "link" of REST Service?